# What do I do when I change poetry pyproject.toml?

Tags: python-poetry

I have a `pyproject.toml` and I already did `poetry init` (obviously) and `poetry install`.

If I change the toml file by hand, what exactly do I have to do?

On the one hand I think I have to synchronize the `poetry.lock` file but do I erase it and do install again?
I have conflicting ideas on how to proceed after an edit of the toml file.

Also, is the procedure the same if I do a `poetry add` instead of editing the toml manually?

Answer (score 7):

Whenever you change Poetry related stuff in your `pyproject.toml` run `poetry lock --no-update` afterwards to sync the `poetry.lock` files with those changes. The `--no-update` flag tries to preserve existing versions of dependencies. Once the lock file is updated run `poetry install` to sync your venv with the locked dependencies.

Wherever possible you should prefer using Poetry's cli instead of manually edit the `pyproject.toml`. Poetry will take care of the steps described above for you. So if you run `poetry add <somedep>`, Poetry will add the entry to your `pyproject.toml`, update the `poetry.lock` and will install necessary dependencies.

Comment: Do I need the `poetry install` after the `poetry lock --no-update` command?

Comment: Yes, because `poetry lock` only update the lock file, but it will not install anything.